# Alternatives to Thuuz website to check interesting sports games?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have been a happy user of Thuuz.com for a good while to check which sport games were most interesting but they have recently shut down the website and they only use iPhone/Android apps.

Any other option to still check information of the same kind as in Thuuz on a standard website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are You Watching This?!

http://areyouwatchingthis.com

Comment: Any website that ranks Tour de France 2012 Cycling etapes?